# Why byte level functions are required to read a text file?

Tags: programming-languages

Why byte level functions are required to read a text file. I mean after all it's a file containing an array of string. Then why it can't be stored in a string directly. Why in any language ( java, c, c++ or as3) byte level functions need to be used to read them ?

It could be quite easier if i could do something like this :

```
var a_str:String = new String();

var myFile:File  ;

a_str = String( myFile.read("xyz.txt") ) ;

trace ( a_str ) ; // << content of the file xyz.txt
```

Comment: How about learning a bit about contemporary processor architectures, disks, file systems, etc. etc. You will find that almost everything is made up of bytes, or blocks of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you store an end of file with characters? For any reasonable length sequence of characters you can think of, there is a possibility that it will appear in the text and be treated as an end of file and prematurely ending the file.

Comment: I think, could be done if a standard was created that "blah blah" special set of characters would represent end of file, return etc.

Comment: No matter what text characters are used, you will always have the problem of collision. That is why it is defined without using text characters.

Comment: The notion of a formal "eof" marker is a bit odd. The end of a file in any encoding could, realistically, simply be the literal EOF. The corresponding reader would have to recognize if EOF has been passed in the middle of reading an MBCS character, however.

Answer (score 1):

Because not all text is rendered equally. Some older character sets represent themselves in one-byte characters, while other sets are multi-byte. As a result, writers for each have to be able to manipulate bytes, not just characters.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer? Memory is typically byte-addressable, so reading a file you would expect the same thing. In most C-style programming languages, a string is typically just a collection of bytes, typically terminated by null character, `NUL` (0x00).

Comment: -1: NUL-terminated (not NULL, that's a pointer) "strings" are only used in C. Even early Pascal stored the length separately and thus allowed NUL characters (though with length limitations), and quite a few of today's major languages have unicode strings with a length field. *Files* are indeed bytes, but it's comparatively easy (though you shouldn't half-ass it) for programming languages to provide the abstraction of *text* without concern for character encodings as long as it remains a strings (instead of going, say, to the network or disk).

Comment: @delnan I edited my answer to reflect your comments. I was really only thinking of C because that's what many of the modern programming languages and operating systems are based on.

Comment: What do you consider "C-style programming languages"? Typical candidates like C++, Java and C# all have non-NUL-terminated string types, and two of those three use unicode (albeit only UTF-16) for strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of languages which can read a whole file into a string. Python can; I'm pretty sure Perl can. That functionality is built on lower-level functionality that reads files a byte-at-a-time, of course (or, rather, as a sequence of bytes, whether or not a larger chunk is served up).

If you don't like the tools you're using, get some better ones.